# Selecting Some Data From a Bigger Set

Tags: pyparsing

Can someone point me to an example of processing just desired data from a bigger set using pyparsing?  Is a a Parse Action the right way to use an "if" statement?

Consider the table of colleges and game scores given in the Oreilly pamphlet on Pyparsing.  It has data for Florida State and other colleges.  Let's say Florida, Florida State and South Florida were all in the table at random locations.  How would you process just the results from Florida schools?

Later in the document a loop is used over all the data and I could put my if statement there but I feel maybe I don't understand when to use a Parse Action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parse action to add further validation to data that has matched the defined parsing rules, but may fail some semantic rule. Here is a case where a parse action is used on an expression that matches any integer, but the parse action permits only even integers:

```
from pyparsing import *

integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))

even_integer = integer.copy()
def onlyEvensAllowed(tokens):
    if tokens[0] % 2 != 0:
        # reject this integer by raising a ParseException
        raise ParseException('only even numbers allowed')
even_integer.addParseAction(onlyEvensAllowed)


sample = "92873 234 2934 2934 292394 239847 293879237 2398 293492"

number = even_integer | integer.suppress()
print OneOrMore(number).parseString(sample)
```

Prints:

```
[234, 2934, 2934, 292394, 2398, 293492]
```

In the case of the college game scores, you could do a similar filtering parse action, accepting only college names containing the string "Florida", and raising a ParseException if they don't.